# Android Studio - XML Properties don't come up in code suggestion

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I try to type the properties (e.g. `android:width` or `android:height` etc.) for a View or any other component in XML in Android Studio the code completion/suggestion dialog box does not show, Whereas if I try to type the main parent component (like `<Button>` or `<TextView>` etc.) it pops up with the code suggestion box.

I've tried:

- Invalidating Cache.
- Turning off Power Saving mode.

and none of them worked. So please, Help me.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use compileSdkVersion 33, upgrade your Android Studio to Dolphin.

It worked for me.

Comment: that seems like a valid solution because i did upgrade it to compileSdkVersion 33

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The problem was that I was using CompileSdk33 which is not supported by Android Studio Chipmunk. So to fix this problem update your android studio to Android Studio - Electric Eel or Android Studio - Dolphin

Comment: You can improve your answer by including a link to the AS-complieSdk version compatibility docs, if you have it